# What does admission mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, dates

I’m confused. If it is said that “admission starts on [insert date here]”, does this mean I shall wait and apply on the given date of admission or am I supposed to apply as soon as possible and wait till the given date for admission perhaps would mean “application result” in this case. What does admission refer to in this context?

Comment: "It" is probably just sloppily-worded - most likely what's meant there is *the **process of applying for** admission* starts on some date. But this isn't something that can be worked out using a dictionary. If the exact intended meaning matters to you, ask ***them*** to clarify (they must ***know***, but we can only ***guess***).

Comment: It's ambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context, **admission** means that is the date at which the school begins admitting students. No-one will be admitted before that date. The implication is that you can **apply** beforehand, and you probably should, as it will take time for the school to process all the applications.